# Extracting borders from country polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, line, linestring

I'm trying to convert a polygon GeoJSON of countries into a line layer that contains *only the borders*. It should **not** contain the edges of the polygons that border the ocean (in my polygon dataset, nothing).

How can I in QGIS 3.8 do that? Basically, "give me the linestring of this polygon data, but only where there is a polygon on both sides of it".

I've checked similar answers and they don't cover this case. Most importantly, I actually want the data, not just set the display fill style to none.

Comment: What is your success by so far?

Comment: I know how to convert polygons into lines. But not how to exclude the ocean/nothing edges.

Comment: Am I correctly understanding that you want to leave only those parts of borders that do not `intersect` with the ocean? Why not try some sort of `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference ...`?

Comment: Nothing intersects, all my polygons are flush with each other. I don't have a polygon where the ocean is, though I could possibly create one if that would help.

Comment: Create or acquire a polygon of the ocean. Then use the `Difference` tool as suggested by Taras.

Comment: This worked well. Polygons to lines, then Difference gives me what I want. I also excluded lakes the same way. @Taras - write it up as a short answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume there are two layers *'borders'* (line) and *'ocean'* (polygon), see image below.

[image: input]

With the ["Difference"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) geoalgorithm can be found under `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference`, it is possible to delete edges of the polygons that border the ocean.

The output new *'borders'* layer will look as following

[image: result]

Keep on mind that this object is a [`MULTILINESTRING`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OGC_Validity).

[image: object]

In case, these features should be treated as a simple [`LINESTRING`](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html#linestrings), please proceed with ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) can be found under `Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to singleparts`.

There is a useful subject on this topic, see [Convert MultiLineString to LineString using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271027/convert-multilinestring-to-linestring-using-qgis)

Comment: Note: This also works if the polygons are touching, but not overlapping (e.g. in my use-case, they share a line, exact coordinates identical, I just didn't use topology) and Difference cuts out those shared lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no ocean polygons, the following should still work if the country polygons are perfect (no gaps).

1. Dissolve the countries to create "land"
2. Convert the country polygons to lines
3. Keep only intersections with "land"

In case you have issues with gaps between countries, add a tiny positive buffer to the "land" layer before intersecting it. If, conversely, you would still be picking up the shoreline borders after intersecting, do a small negative buffer of the "land" layer.